# Virtualbox list vrde port for vm on commandline

Tags: bash, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a Virtualbox VM that is configured with VRDE for remote access using RDP. I'm familiar with how to set the vrde port, but for a given VM I have not found a way to query the current vrde port value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use:

```
$ vboxmanage showvminfo testvm | grep VRDE:
VRDE:            enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 3398, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
```